# Systemd.path: How to tell which PathChanged?

Tags: systemd

Trying to monitor 3 different folders and run a script when one changes. The problem is the script needs to know which folder changed, and I can't seem to find a way to pass that.

```
[Path]
PathChanged=/x/y/z
PathChanged=/a/b/c
PathChanged=/foo/bar
Unit=123.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm assuming there just isn't a way to do it. And that I need to either have 3 separate .path files(gross), or have the script just iterate through all 3 folders every time one of them changes(inefficient and also gross).

But I figured I'd ask here. Perhaps there's a systemd variable I'm missing, or a more efficient way to do it without systemd. So is there?

Thanks.

Comment: «way without systemd» : you want [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)??

Comment: Yeah, looks like I do. Found this similar question: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/706778/how-to-know-which-file-or-inode-triggered-a-systemd-path-unit) and looks like they gave up on it. Such a weird omission.

Comment: [systemd.path(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) says: "Internally, path units use the inotify(7) API to monitor file systems."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some playing I found the easiest way was to use one `*.path` file per path and template each path into a single `*@.service` file.  Here's something using your example:

```
$ systemctl --user cat 123* *.path
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/123@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo %I

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/abc.path
[Path]
PathChanged=/a/b/c
Unit=123@-a-b-c.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/foobar.path
[Path]
PathChanged=/foo/bar
Unit=123@-foo-bar.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/xyz.path
[Path]
PathChanged=/x/y/z
Unit=123@-x-y-z.service
```

The `*.service` can access the path through the `%I` [specifier](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers)

To get the`Unit=` names, I used [systemd-escape](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html):

```
$ systemd-escape --template=123@.service \
      '/x/y/z' \
      '/a/b/c' \
      '/foo/bar'
123@-x-y-z.service 123@a-b-c.service 123@-foo-bar.service
```

Relevant man pages:

- [systemd.path(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html)
- [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)
- [systemd.service(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)
- [systemd-escape(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html)
- [systemd-unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

In case you're wondering whether there is an easier solution, here are the things I tried:

---

## Experiment 1

### Hypothesis: It's in an environment variable.

[systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes) gives a list of environment variables.  It's possible that something like `$RUNTIME_DIRECTORY` or `$LISTEN_FDS` is set.

### Experiment Setup:

```
$ mkdir /home/stew/systemdpath
$ systemctl --user cat simplepath.*
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simplepath.path
[Unit]
Description=Path testing

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/home/stew/systemdpath

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simplepath.service
[Unit]
Description=Path testing unit

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env
$ systemctl --user start simplepath.path
```

### Experiment Results:

```
$ touch ~/systemdpath/file
$ journalctl --user simplepath.service
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian systemd[31634]: Starting Path testing unit...
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: HOME=/home/stew
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: LOGNAME=stew
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: PATH=/home/stew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: SHELL=/bin/bash
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: USER=stew
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/i3
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: DISPLAY=:0
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: PWD=/home/stew
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: SHLVL=1
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XAUTHORITY=/home/stew/.Xauthority
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=i3
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=i3
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session5
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: MANAGERPID=31634
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: INVOCATION_ID=837f6b2e56b543c9b51cda4ee8952fa8
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian env[334512]: JOURNAL_STREAM=8:21581980
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian systemd[31634]: simplepath.service: Succeeded.
Jul 28 08:26:16 stewbian systemd[31634]: Finished Path testing unit
```

### Conclusion:

Systemd does not put the path into an environment variable.

---

## Experiment 2

### Hypothesis: It can be templated

Thinking of `$LISTEN_FDS` there are some parallels between socket and paths.  Sockets are templated when [`Accept=yes`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#Description) is set, so what if we try that with paths?

### Initial setup:

```
$ systemctl --user cat simplepath*
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simplepath.path
[Unit]
Description=Path testing

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/home/stew/systemdpath
Unit=simplepath@.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/simplepath@.service
[Unit]
Description=Path testing unit

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo %i
```

### Experiment Results:

```
$ systemctl --user start simplepath.path
$ touch ~/systemdpath/file
$ journalctl --user --since "5 minutes ago"
Jul 28 09:14:25 stewbian systemd[31634]: Starting Path testing unit...
Jul 28 09:14:25 stewbian echo[336171]: simplepath
Jul 28 09:14:25 stewbian systemd[31634]: simplepath@simplepath.service: Succeeded.
```

### Conclusion

The instance echo'd in the service was the service name itself. That doesn't help.

---

## Experiment 3

### Hypothesis: Each path can have its own file and template the service

### Experiment Setup:

```
$ mkdir ~/path1
$ mkdir ~/path2
$ systemctl --user cat path*
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/path1.path
[Unit]
Description=Path1 testing

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=%h/path1
Unit=paths@path1.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/path2.path
[Unit]
Description=Path2 testing

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=%h/path2
Unit=paths@path2.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/paths@.service
[Unit]
Description=Path testing unit

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo %h/%i
$ systemctl --user start path1.path path2.path
```

### Experiment:

```
$ touch ~/path1
$ touch ~/path2
$ journalctl --user --since "5 minutes ago"
Jul 28 09:43:45 stewbian systemd[31634]: Starting Path testing unit...
Jul 28 09:43:45 stewbian echo[336517]: /home/stew/path1
Jul 28 09:43:45 stewbian systemd[31634]: paths@path1.service: Succeeded.
Jul 28 09:43:45 stewbian systemd[31634]: Finished Path testing unit.
Jul 28 09:43:50 stewbian systemd[31634]: Starting Path testing unit...
Jul 28 09:43:50 stewbian echo[336519]: /home/stew/path2
Jul 28 09:43:50 stewbian systemd[31634]: paths@path2.service: Succeeded.
Jul 28 09:43:50 stewbian systemd[31634]: Finished Path testing unit.
```

### Conclusion

You can have a single templated service unit working for several path units.  This seems to be the simplest approach.

The problem I ran into here is that the service uses `%h` which is the home directory.  I had problems when I included the `/` character in the template names.  [systemd-escape(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html) seems to help out with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extremely well detailed answer!

Comment: Maybe the version of systemd used by @Stewart didn't provide TRIGGER_UNIT and TRIGGER_PATH environment variables for .path services in the past, but the version I just used (252.12) includes them.  I tested this using rootless docker, not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: Upon further investigation TRIGGER_PATH always shows the first PathChanged= path in the list even if I touch one of the other directories.  This seems like a bug!

Answer (score 0):

On some Linux before the introduction of systemd (like RedHat 6.x) we could install and use incrontab command which is much simpler and complete than systemd.path solution.
Incrontab and incrond provide a powerful interface to inotify api but unfortunatly it was replaced by systemd.path which is incomplete compared with incrontab.
I guess incrontab can be still installed on current releases that use systemd, but it's by far unmaintained, so, it isn't elegible for a production and or critical system.
I hope this to be fixed in future releases.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you described *how* to use incrontab to solve the OP’s problem.