# Obtaining file path in the systemd service unit triggered from path unit

Tags: systemd, inotify

I need to trigger a script whenever a new file shows up in a directory. The old implementation uses [incrontab](https://man.archlinux.org/man/incrontab.5). To add an `inotify` watch via `incrontab` I simply add a line per directory as follows

```
/dir/to/watch IN_CLOSE_WRITE /script/to/call $@/$#
```

Whenever a file is written, my script is called with an argument - a path to the newly created file.

I am switching from `incrontab` directory watcher to [systemd path](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.path.5.en) unit:

```
[Path]
PathChanged=/dir/to/watch
```

When the corresponding service unit is called I need to somehow retrieve the name of the new file that triggered the event. The closest I found was to use `TRIGGER_PATH` [variable](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.exec.5.en#Environment_Variables_Set_or_Propagated_by_the_Service_Manager) initialized by the path unit. The problem is that the variable is set to `/dir/to/watch` directory and not the newly created file.

I need to know the specific file name, but I can't find a way to get if from systemd.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. What are you doing with the files that trigger your service? If they can moved into a new directory, you know that anything in the watched directory hasn't been processed yet. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600642/systemd-path-how-to-tell-which-pathchanged/600686#600686) has some suggestions, but that's only appropriate if you're watch for *specific* files.

Comment: @larsks It is a directory with configuration files, so moving them out is not an option.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/28939